# Knockout computed var not firing subscription

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Not sure why the subscription is not firing for the computed variable. Any thoughts?

```
                self.TeamFilter        = ko.observableArray(["PWx","FRT"]);
                self.FilteredQueueList = ko.pureComputed(() => {
                    console.log('computing..');
                    let teamsArray = self.QueueListCached();          
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(teamsArray, (team) => {
                        let toFilter = false;

                        TeamFilter().forEach((filterText, idx) => {
                            toFilter = toFilter || (team.queue_name).indexOf(filterText) > -1;
                        });
                        console.log('computed');
                        return toFilter;
                    });
                }).extend({
                    notify: 'always'
                });

                self.FilteredQueueList.subscribe((newQueueList) => {
                    //self.QueueList.removeAll();
                    console.log('FilteredQueueList changed!');
                    //self.QueueList(self.FilteredQueueList());
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(newQueueList, null, 2));
                });
```

The console.logs within the computed callback are getting fired. So i know that the computed variable is getting created. In this case, I am simply filtering an Observable array.

But the subscription console.log won't fire, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Your code looks ok.
can you please create a fiddle for it and explain how you are using observable array and pureComputed variable in your HTML.

Comment: `TeamFilter()` should be `self.TeamFilter()` also make sure your main computed function returns a value.